# How to sort polymorphic objects in Java by using Arrays.sort

Tags: java

I'm studying implement an interface and abstract class and here it comes to this question that I'm struggling with. I hope you guys can help me out with this question and I'm looking for an explanation in order to understand the code. Any advice is welcome and truly appreciate.

I have been trying to run the code to get the output but it does not work. I think `C` is an answer but I'm not sure.

Here is the question: Which of the following will order an array of Student objects by last name, then by credits (if two students have the same last name) if you were to pass the array of Students to the `Arrays.sort()` method?

```java
Student[] list;
// The array is created and filled with Student objects...
Arrays.sort(list);

/*A*/ public class Student implements Comparable {
    private String lastName;
    private int credits;

   public int compareTo(Student s) {
        int result = lastName.compareTo( s.getLastName() );
        if (result != 0)
            return result;
        else
            return credits - s.getCredits();
    }
}
/*B*/ public class Student implements Comparable {
    private String lastName;
    private int credits;

   public int compareTo(Object o) {
        int result = credits - ( ((Student) o).getCredits() );
        if (result != 0)
            return result;
        else
            return lastName.compareTo( ((Student) o).getLastName() );
    }
}
/*C*/ public class Student {
    private String lastName;
    private int credits;

   public int compareTo(Object o) {
        result = lastName.compareTo( ((Student) o).getLastName() );
        if (result != 0)
            return result;
        else
            return credits - ( ((Student) o).getCredits() );
    }
}
/*D*/ public class Student implements Comparable {
    private String lastName;
    private int credits;

   public int compareTo(Object o) {
        int result = lastName.compareTo( ((Student) o).getLastName() );
        if (result != 0)
            return result;
        else
            return credits - ( ((Student) o).getCredits() );
    }
}
```

Comment: You actually wrote 4 functional solutions and you can't determine which is correct?

Comment: @SMA `A` does not implement raw `Comparable` because it doesn't provide `compareTo(Object)`. `D` does.

Comment: I think C is the one...I'm not sure about my answer.

Comment: @Nin D is the answer.

Comment: @SMA would you mind explain why D is the answer to me specifically? Because I want to understand rather than just the answer.

Comment: @Nin answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is D because:

a. Implements Comparable, but without generics meaning then `compareTo` method should be implemented as `public int compareTo(Object object)` as opposed to `public int compareTo(Student....)`

b. implements interface correctly, but then it first compares credit as opposed to last name which is why its not the answer.

c. Doesn't implement Comparable interface.

d. Does exactly what we want and implements Comparable as expected.